# Violin Bowing Marcato

Tags: technique, violin, bowing

I've been playing the violin for quite some time but somehow seemed to miss what marcato is. How do you play it? Does it have a symbol or text that tells you when to play it? I understand spiccato, staccato and ricochet and col legno. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Marcato means basically to play an accent on every note, or to "mark" them.

It can be notated with the word "marcato," or written on each note with an accent mark that looks like an upside down "V," like here:

[image: Upside Down V over note!]
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcato)

This video explains it very well:

Enjoy!